# ART makes Facebook app non installable (Error: -24)

Tags: google-play-store, facebook, dalvik, art

I have an Android 4.4.2 phone and I enabled ART instead of Dalvik.

When I go to the Google Play Store and try to install Facebook, it can't install the app.

I get two errors, sometimes I get

> Invalid installation package

and sometimes

> Error -24

Is there a way to know what's going on?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the facebook app is not compatible with the ART runtime? Some apps may work straight out of Playstore with ART, others don't. ART ***is not yet*** ready for prime-time!

Comment: @t0mm13b Hi! Yes, I considered it. But if you take a look at the [ART compatibility list](http://www.androidruntime.com/list) it seems that facebook is fully compatible. Also, every friend of mine that switched to ART can use facebook without issues, even with custom roms. Is there something I can do to try to find what's the problem on my phone? P.s. I also tried installing facebook on dalvik and switching to ART after installation. If I do such thing, the phone goes to reboot loop

Comment: To add on, facebook works fine for me and im running ART

Comment: It's an experimental feature in 4.4.  Please direct bug reports to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem. To fix it I did the following:

Uninstall Facebook,
Wipe dalvik cache via recovery,
Reinstall Facebook,
Reboot device,
Sign in to Facebook.

Comment: Read the question: I'm not even able to install facebook. And if I install it on dalvik, then clear cache and switch to ART, i get a boot loop

Comment: I'm not saying switch to dalvik, I'm saying clear the cache via the clear dalvik cache command in recovery.

Comment: Tried, it's the same, I can't install facebook

Answer (score 0):

Try switching back to Dalvik --> Install Facebook --> switch back to ART. It's working fine for me, i just happened to have installed it before switching to ART